# Loading a single player world crashes with an Internal Exception

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When trying single player mode, a Java error appears:

```
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: bit cannot be cast to fm
```

However I can play on multiplayer just fine. I'm running Minecraft 1.7.2 and have no mods installed.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I did some searching and it looks like you've typed out the error message wrong. Could you please carefully retype it so that it matches the error exactly, or just take a screenshot of the error message and post that in your question (using the edit button)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix from http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2061396-172-error-when-loading-world/

> - Go to main menu
> - Go to options
> - Go to video options
> - Set render distance to 2 chunks
> - Put FPS on unlimited

Comment: Those changes allowed a new world to be generated but later when trying to reload it, the same error appears.   Its updated to the current version of Minecraft and no mods are installed.

Comment: oop error should read internal exception; java.lang.ClassCastException: bit cannot be cast to fm.                                                        Thanks for answering everbody, this is the only forum I've been on where anyone has sent a response about this.   crap sorry double post.

Comment: @user58464 You can delete comments. Hover over and a small X will appear at the end.

Comment: ah ok hadn't noticed it. This laptops not aged well, old graphics card warning shows in main Minecraft menu. I used to have to adjust graphics setting in control panel to do MC. Though that doesn't need changed anymore with the recent version, adjusting it doesn't fix this either. May just end getting a new system in a few months. Although weirdly it plays on a multi server just fine.